# make fails for gcc compiled Perl V5.8.8 on AIX 6.1

Tags: perl, aix

I got gcc to compile Perl V5.8.8 on AIX 6.1 due to stated cc_r issues while attempting to install CPAN. We do not have the IBM C compiler but using gcc and it "successfully compiled", I hope as no errors, ran make per:

```
make
    make depend MAKEDEPEND=
    sh ./makedepend MAKE=make
    sh writemain lib/auto/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.a  > perlmain.c
    echo  av.c scope.c op.c doop.c doio.c dump.c hv.c mg.c reentr.c perl.c perly.c pp.c pp_hot.c
pp_ctl.c pp_sys.c regcomp.c regexec.c utf8.c gv.c sv.c taint.c toke.c util.c deb.c run.c universal.c xsutils.c pad.c globals.c perlio.c perlapi.c numeric.c locale.c pp_pack.c pp_sort.c miniperlmain.c perlmain.c opmini.c | tr ' ' '\n' >.clist
Finding dependencies for av.o.
Finding dependencies for scope.o.
Finding dependencies for op.o.
Finding dependencies for doop.o.
Finding dependencies for doio.o.
Finding dependencies for dump.o.
Finding dependencies for hv.o.
Finding dependencies for mg.o.
Finding dependencies for reentr.o.
Finding dependencies for perl.o.
Finding dependencies for perly.o.
Finding dependencies for pp.o.
Finding dependencies for pp_hot.o.
Finding dependencies for pp_ctl.o.
Finding dependencies for pp_sys.o.
Finding dependencies for regcomp.o.
Finding dependencies for regexec.o.
Finding dependencies for utf8.o.
Finding dependencies for gv.o.
Finding dependencies for sv.o.
Finding dependencies for taint.o.
Finding dependencies for toke.o.
Finding dependencies for util.o.
Finding dependencies for deb.o.
Finding dependencies for run.o.
Finding dependencies for universal.o.
Finding dependencies for xsutils.o.
Finding dependencies for pad.o.
Finding dependencies for globals.o.
Finding dependencies for perlio.o.
Finding dependencies for perlapi.o.
Finding dependencies for numeric.o.
Finding dependencies for locale.o.
Finding dependencies for pp_pack.o.
Finding dependencies for pp_sort.o.
Finding dependencies for miniperlmain.o.
Finding dependencies for perlmain.o.
Finding dependencies for opmini.o.
echo Makefile.SH cflags.SH config_h.SH makeaperl.SH makedepend.SH  makedir.SH myconfig.SH writemain.SH pod/Makefile.SH | tr ' ' '\n' >.shlist
Updating makefile...
     test -s perlmain.c && touch perlmain.c
    cd x2p; make depend
    sh ../makedepend MAKE=make
    echo hash.c  str.c util.c walk.c | tr ' ' '\n' >.clist
Finding dependencies for hash.o.
Finding dependencies for str.o.
Finding dependencies for util.o.
Finding dependencies for walk.o.
    echo Makefile.SH cflags.SH | tr ' ' '\n' >.shlist
Updating makefile...
    `sh  cflags "optimize='-O'" miniperlmain.o`  miniperlmain.c
      CCCMD =  gcc -maix64 -DPERL_CORE -c -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -maix64 -DUSE_64_BIT_ALL -O  -Wall
In file included from perl.h:496,
             from miniperlmain.c:36:
/usr/include/unistd.h:924: error: expected ')' before '[' token
/usr/include/unistd.h:925: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'rid_t'
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
```

Output from offending lines in /usr/include/unistd.h:

```
    extern int              setroles(rid_t [], int);
    extern int              getroles(pid_t, rid_t [], int);
"/usr/include/unistd.h" [Read only] The cursor is at line 924 of 966 --91%-- .
```

again, any help is GREATLY appreciated.........  LT

PS. while IBM states Perl V5.10.x is not packaged/supported on AIX 6.1, will it actually run correctly anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You're very unlikely to get decent community support for anything but current versions of Perl, as of 2011 this means [v5.14](http://perl.org/get.html).

`#perl-help`'s opinions:

```
<Khisanth> looks like some missing header files
<Khisanth> or missing #includes
<DrForr> Whatever defines rid_t is a likely candidate.
```